# How did the child escape the space suit?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Season 6 two-part opener of *Doctor Who*, we see a child who is stuck inside a space suit.  We learn she was put there by The Silence to keep her safe.  Later on in the story we find that she somehow escaped the suit, but it's not explained how.  How did she pull this off?

Sorry about lack of names, I'm purposefully not using names to avoid spoiling people who haven't seen all of Season 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commented on in the episode:

> RIVER: She climbed out of this suit. Like she forced her way out. She
>   must be incredibly strong.
>
> DOCTOR: Incredibly strong and running away. I like her.

The suit was in effect an incubation capsule that provided life support but also built up her strength, etc.  In the end the girl got strong enough to tear herself out of it when she got scared enough to do so in order to run away.